# Largest number data type in C

Tags: c, types, numbers

So I wrote a simple C program which displays the nth fibonacci number based on user specification. I started using ints and obviously that did not work out too well so I then went to floats, longs, and finally long longs. Even with long longs there is a cut off to where I get nonsensical or incorrect output such as negative numbers ( starts to happen a bit before n = 100 ). Is there anything I can do to expand the range of this program or is there no way to fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  long long term = 0;
  long long val = 0;
  long long first = 0;
  long long second = 1;

  printf( "Which fibonacci term (starting at 0) would you like to see? ");
  scanf("%lld", &term );

  if( term == 0 )
  {
    printf("%lld\n", first );

    return 1;
  }

  if( term == 1 )
  {
    printf( "%lld\n", second );

    return 1;
  }

  if( term > 1 )
  {  
    for( int i = 1; term > i; i++ )
    {
      val = first + second;

      first = second;
      second = val;
    } 

    printf( "%lld\n", val );

    return 1;

  }

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Find a big number library.

Comment: You can use `unsigned long long` - that's about the widest you can get if you don't want to use big integer libraries

Comment: Make your own data type.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves: even with an unsigned 64-bit long long, the value will overflow before fib(100) (it overflows at fib(94) to be exact, I think).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per ISO C99, a long long is 64bit at the minimum - the standard integer data type with the largest size. Your compiler may allow for larger types, and these are defined by `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t` in `<stdint.h>`.

However, I would strongly recommend using a Bigint library such as GMP.
Using GMP, the only limitation for long integers and floating points is the resources available on the system.

Comment: +1 for `uintmax_t`.  That's the maximum that the compiler supports.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler …in theory. In practice my compiler has `__int128` but defines `intmax_t` as the 64-bit `long long`.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Mine too, but GCC doesn't fully support the 128-bit types — and the libraries typically don't either, so there isn't a sane way to print an `__int128` value.  In fact, you can't even write a `__int128` literal that is larger than a 64-bit number.

Answer (score 1):

Change all of your types to `unsigned long long` which will perform unsigned arithmetic, nearly doubling the range. If you wish to extend this further you will need to create your own data type. A few examples of libraries that can do this for you:

- [GMP](http://gmplib.org/)
- [OpenSSL BN](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/bn.html)

Edit per Michael Burr's comment:

- Requires your platform to have unsigned long longs that are greater than 64 bits, such as 128 bits (or more). C99 only guarantees that long long is **at least** 64 bits. The range of your particular program won't change if long long is only 64 bits.

Comment: You might want to include a tip on using multiple numbers to form a larger one...

Comment: Even with an unsigned 64-bit long long, the value will overflow before fib(100).  If your platform has 128 bit unsigned long longs, it'll go a while longer. Up to fib(186).

Comment: Good points. Edited to cover the fact that C99 only guarantees long long is >= 64 bits and added alternative options / example libraries.

Answer (score 0):

One can use `uintmax_t` but that is likely <= 128 bits.

[GMP](https://gmplib.org/) is an excellent library to consider.

But one only needs to write an extend precision `add()` as below.  Not very efficient, but it gets the job done for `fib()`.  Here I use a C string as the data type. Other types of your design could work far more better.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define max(a, b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))

// "Add" 2 strings
char *strsum(const char *a, const char *b) {
  size_t alen = strlen(a);
  size_t blen = strlen(b);
  size_t clen = max(alen, blen) + 1;
  size_t csize = clen + 1;
  char *c = malloc(csize);
  if (c == NULL) return NULL;
  c[clen] = '\0';
  int carry = 0;
  while (alen > 0 && blen > 0) {
    int sum = a[--alen] - '0' + b[--blen] - '0' + carry;
    c[--clen] = sum%10 + '0';
    carry = sum / 10;
  }
  while (alen > 0) {
    int sum = a[--alen] - '0' + carry;
    c[--clen] = sum%10 + '0';
    carry = sum / 10;
  }
  while (blen > 0) {
    int sum = b[--blen] - '0' + carry;
    c[--clen] = sum%10 + '0';
    carry = sum / 10;
  }
  if (carry) {
    c[--clen] = carry + '0';
  }
  if (clen > 0) {
    memmove(&c[0], &c[1], csize - 1);
  }
  return c;
}

void fib(unsigned n) {
  char *a = NULL;
  char *b = malloc(2); strcpy(b, "0");
  char *c = malloc(2); strcpy(c, "1");
  unsigned i;
  for (i=1; i<n; i++) {
    free(a);
    a = b;
    b = c;
    c = strsum(a, b);
    if (c == NULL) break;
    printf("fib(%u) = %s\n", i+1, c);
  }
  free(a);
  free(b);
  free(c);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  fib(1000);
  return 0;
}
```

Sample

```
fib(2) = 1
fib(3) = 2
fib(4) = 3
fib(5) = 5
fib(6) = 8
fib(7) = 13
fib(8) = 21
fib(9) = 34
fib(10) = 55
...
fib(93) = 12200160415121876738 /* max using 64-bit math */
...
fib(100) = 354224848179261915075
...
fib(1000) = 43466557686937456435688527675040625802564660517371780402481729089536555417949051890403879840079255169295922593080322634775209689623239873322471161642996440906533187938298969649928516003704476137795166849228875
...
fib(10000) = 336...(2084 digits)...875
```